# Laravel connect to a SQL Server 2008 named instance

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, freetds

I am trying to connect an SQL server from an Ubuntu machine, everythings works great except for named instances:

**this works**

```
'data' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'xxxx',
            'port'     => 1433,
            'database' => 'db',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pwd',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
```

**this doesn't**

```
  'data' => array(
                'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
                'host'     => 'yyyy\NAMEDINSTANCE',
                'port'     => 1433,
                'database' => 'db',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pwd',
                'prefix'   => '',
            ),
```

I always end up with this error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)' in /var/www/public/my.api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
```

I have tried every possible combination:

- host **\** INSTANCE
- host **/** INSTANCE
- host **\\** INSTANCE

Can someone help me ?

**Edit**:
Because I have also tried without instance name ([as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905596/php-pdo-connection-to-mssql-instance)), the script keep trying to connect until I get this error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)' in /var/www/public/my.api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
```

Any editor as Management studio, DBeaver or Database.NET can connect to that instance only by specifying the **INSTANCENAME**, so it seems more a PDO problem witht the DSN

I also have tried to connect to that named instance directly with `tsql` without any more luck:

```
tsql -S SERVER -U usr -P pwd -L dbname
```

Here the `/etc/freetds.conf` file:

```
[global]
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
        port = 1433
        dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
        dump file append = yes
        text size = 64512

[SERVER]
        host = ip
        port = 1433
        instance = instance_name

[SERVER2]
        host = ip
        port = 1433
```

And the tds log file:

```
log.c:196:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.91
        on 2015-03-19 15:35:46 with debug flags 0x4fff.
iconv.c:330:tds_iconv_open(0xc163a0, UTF-8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:349:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:351:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:391:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:394:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:205:Connecting to 195.70.16.92 port 1433 (TDS version 7.1)
net.c:270:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:306:getsockopt(2) reported: Connection timed out
net.c:316:tds_open_socket() failed
util.c:331:tdserror(0xc16140, 0xc163a0, 20009, 110)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
```

Of course, if I try to connect to **SERVER2** (which is a non named instance) everything goes smoothly...

Comment: Try setting the port number to `NULL`, and use `'host'     => 'yyyy\NAMEDINSTANCE'`

Comment: same error, I have updated my question with more tests, `tsql` give me a timeout with a named instance, so I suspect being more a freeTDS problem than a PDO problem

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez works like a charm...years down the line. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a solution, there were two problems :

- The SQL server wasn't listening on the good default port (my bad)
- Laravel (PDO ?) doesn't know how to handle (or at least I haven't found how) named instances, I have tried any possible combination (see Question)

So I finally used a combination of FreeTDS DSN with laravel in order to connect the SQL named instance server.

The **/etc/freetds.conf** DSN configuration:

```
[NAMED_INSTANCE]
   host = 127.0.0.1
   port = 55021
```

And in the laravel database adapter:

```
'webcmd' => array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => 'NAMED_INSTANCE',
    'database' => 'db',
    'username' => 'usr',
    'password' => 'pwd',
    'prefix'   => '',
),
```

And that solved my problem, hope it'll help someone too

Comment: This is save my day

Comment: Thanks for this!! On ubuntu 16.04 with ppa:ondrej/php, I had to run this first: sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase freetds-common libsybdb5

Answer (score 1):

hi i was with this problem but i solved it.
I'm using docker, I installed the latest version of laravel with curl ([curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash](https://laravel.build/example-app%20%7C%20bash)), this installation contains php8.0, laravel 8.0 and Ubuntu 21.04.
modify the Dockerfile and add the following libraries:

```
nano unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-common freetds-dev tdsodbc freetds-bin php8.0-sybase
```

The last one (php8.0-sybase) is important, since it will allow you to carry out migrations.

Also, add the following to the file:

```
RUN echo "[sqlserver] \ n \
host = IPSERVER \ n \
port = 1433 \ n \
tds version = 7.3 ">> /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
```

as I wanted to connect to MS sql server 2008 I put tds version = 7.3, according to the FREETDS documentation. (https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html)

then in the laravel .env file modify the connection to the database:

```
DB_CONNECTION = sqlsrv
DB_HOST = sqlserver // the same one that was configured in the freetds.conf file
DB_PORT = 1433
DB_DATABASE = databasename
DB_USERNAME = username
DB_PASSWORD = password
```

and in the laravel database.php file, change the default connection:

```
'default' => env ('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

and that's it.

**microsoft drivers never worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the participation to solve this connection problem. I also encountered this problem, here is how I solved it.

For info in my case the connection with tsql works but not since Laravel (5.4)

One trick I took to understand is that it is not the default port (**1433**) that is used.

To find the port you must start a shell connection:

```
tsql -D DB -S "IP\INSTANCE" -U login -P pass
```

And check in the logs the good port here is **1168**

> Net.c: 1059: instance port is 1168

Contents of the file **freetds.conf**

```
[global]
    text size = 64512
    dump file = /var/log/freetds.log
    dump file append = yes

[mssql]
    host = MSSQLSRV
    port = 1168
    tds version = auto
    instance = IP\INSTANCE
    dump file = /var/log/freetds.log
    dump file append = yes
```

Contents of the file : config/database.php

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'mssql',
            'port'     => '1168',
            'database' => 'DB',
            'username' => 'login',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

Now everything is working properly.