# Specify MSSQL instance on Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL instance using Laravel (using Laravel 7.X) but for some reason, Laravel is connecting to the default instance only even though I specify an instance "DB_HOST" in .env file.

I have done `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` so I know it isn't that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across this post?  Looks like Laravel might not be able to connect to named instances in mssql.

[Laravel connect to a SQL Server 2008 named instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146304/laravel-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-named-instance)